# Matlab crashing with Internal error fault on using simulink library

Tags: matlab, graphics, crash, simulink

I am using the MATLAB 2015a version from last 1 year but suddenly i am encountering this issue . That whenever I open my simulink I get this error of access violation.

I have tried to Reinstall it but still my problem persists. Even updating my graphic driver to latest one but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Without detailed debugging information, nobody is going to be able to resolve this for you. Even if you had that information, you'd be better off providing it to MathWorks support (i.e. the people you're paying for a license to run your broken software) rather than here, this is not a programming question

Comment: “Suddenly” doesn’t happen in computing. Something changed on your system that causes this issue. Maybe you upgraded some software or driver, or installed a new program, any of which could change the libraries that MATLAB depends on.